# Duplicating bookmarks in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

I'm wondering about something - is there an option or a setting somewhere in Google Chrome that enables you to have duplicate bookmarks in your, well, bookmarks?

In my bookmarks bar I have folders with ... pages of some equipment manufacturers. Every time I'm considering which one are an option, open their pages up, and bookmark them in another folder, let's say called "possible options".

But when bookmarking them for the second time, Chrome removes the **original** bookmark and just saves it in the "possible ..." folder. ***How to avoid that?***

I don't want Chrome *moving* the bookmark, but just to save it again. Redundancy is really not an issue with me, with this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From experimentation, it seems this behavior is only exhibited when using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> dialog to add a bookmark. Hence, Chrome allows for copies of the same bookmark, but a "feature" of the shortcut interface is to move the bookmark if it exists elsewhere. Given this, there are multiple solutions to create copies of bookmarks in separate folders.

1. You can open the bookmark manager with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, then copy and paste bookmarks from inside the manager.
2. You can show the bookmarks bar with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, then drag websites from their address bar icons into multiple folders. You can also use copy and paste here as well.

Admittedly, these are somewhat tedious solutions, but as far as I can tell, there are no other ways.

Comment: Oh, well ... :/

Answer (score 3):

you can.
first access the page, then click the star near the url field, then edit the url and at the last part of the url add #1, #2, AND SO ON MULTIPLE TIMES.

Comment: It will not be the same bookmark that way.

Comment: Yeah, but it works beautifully well!

Comment: Beautiful. I love the easy solution, the #1, #2.